# How to check database is available or not in android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

In my android application I am inserting and displaying data from a SQLite database. Before that I want to check if the database is available or not. That is, I want to check whether the table is available. If it is available,  I also want to check whether it is not empty. Here is the pseudocode

```
if (DB available) {
    if (table available) {
        if (table != empty) {
            insertdata()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can be able to check if you have your db file in the internal storage, if it is there, that means db exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally in Android it's not necessary to check *explicitly* if your database is available. The flow is that you try to get a database instance (in read or write mode) and if the database is not existing, an [onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onCreate%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase%29) procedure is executed, which should execute DDL statement and create database for the first time. In your DDL statement, you can use:

```
create table if not exists TABLE_NAME
```

which will guarantee you that TABLE_NAME exists before you query it.

You can use [`getWritableDatabase()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase%28%29) called on `SQLiteOpenHelper` Object. It will throw [SQLiteException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteException.html) if there's problem with the database.

Check out the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you don't need to check for the existence of a database unless the behaviour of your code is going to change depending on if the database itself is new.  In your case, you would still want to check the contents of the table even if the database isn't new.  If you call `SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase()` WITHOUT passing `CREATE_IF_NECESSARY`, an exception will be thrown.  Normally, though, you would just call `SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase()`.  After that, you would check the table.

You can check for the existence of a table with the statement `SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE name='<tablename>' AND type='table';`